# El estatus de la tarifa telefonica -- se *volverá* activo?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras

Digamos que quiero preguntar sobre el estatus de la tarifa de mi teléfono. Especificamente, sobre el **cambio** que ocurrirá depues de haber recargado el teléfono (su tarifa).

Cómo lo preguntaré?

"El estatus de la tarifa -- se *volverá activo* una ves he añadido el dinero?

Lo que más me interesa es **el verbo del cambio**, *volver* o lo que sea,  que debería o podría ser usado en este caso.

Comment: Saliendo del tema de lo que preguntas, ten en cuenta que si **el estatus** es lo que cambiará, entonces éste se volverá **activo** (y no _activa_), porque estatus es una palabra de género masculino.

Comment: Yo usaría "pasará a ser"

Comment: @SJuan76 "pasará a" o "pasará a estar", mejor que "pasará a ser", ¿cierto?

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta se puede simplificar sin necesidad de ningún verbo extra:

> ¿Se activará la tarifa una vez añadido el dinero?

Comment: Esta es una forma correcta, pero no hace incidencia en el verbo del cambio. Aún así, es cierto que es la que yo usaría de normal.

Comment: En los casos particulares de realizar acciones con empresas de servicios, en mayor grado si estas son telefónicamente, es **fundamental** utilizar la menor cantidad de palabras posibles, todo lo "extra" lleva a interpretaciones erróneas. De hecho la pregunta, supongo está hecha por un no-hispanoparlante, tiene un grado significativo de errores. De ahí los comentarios posteriores.

Comment: No has respondido a mi pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Vale, en un caso como este yo usaría una fórmula como "¿El estatus de la tarifa se actualizará una vez añada el dinero?", siendo "actualizar" un verbo que habla de manera clara del cambio producido; pero si quieres hacer incidir específicamente en que el cambio sea, en concreto, que el estatus pase de inactivo a activo, tal vez una fórmula como "¿El cambio en el estatus de la tarifa se hará efectivo una vez añada el dinero?", o, más simplificadamente "¿El estatus de la tarifa cambiará a activo una vez añada el dinero?".

Entiendo que quieres ver qué posibilidades tienes para designar el cambio como tal y referirte a él, pero entendiendo los matices de cada opción. Siendo esa tu pregunta, mi primera sugerencia da más relevancia al hecho de que se produzca el cambio, en mi segunda sugerencia la relevancia está en el tiempo en que se realiza, y en la tercera en el estatus final, una vez realizado el cambio.